# How to get a button press to ease in and ease out in CSS3?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to get my nav-bar header logo to ease in and out on click/release.

Currently, when you click the logo, the image eases correctly but when you release it snaps back and doesn't ease back into the normal size.

What am I doing wrong with the CSS3?

```css
  .navbar-brand {
    height: 40px;
    width: 182px;
    text-indent: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: url('https://www.sketchappsources.com/resources/source-image/twitterlogo_1x.png') no-repeat left center;
    background-size: auto 40px;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition: 0.2s;
  }
  
  
    .navbar-brand:active {
      transition-timing-function: ease-out;
      transition: .5s;
      transform: scale(.95, .95);
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bd-example" data-example-id="">
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

`transition: ease-in-out all .5s`

instead of

`transition-timing-function` and `transition`

At the moment you are only easing in, not out. You must animate the element in this case, not the :active.

JSfiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/ataue61h/2/

Comment: @AnApprentice No, you should also be using SO's editor.

Comment: @AnApprentice Click snippet in the editor or CTRL+M. Thanks for the downvotes?

Comment: @AnApprentice What browser?

Comment: Just added the snippet to the question. Browser = chrome

Comment: that did it thank you... turns out react was causing a full page refresh due to a bad URL which was killing the ease out. Thanks for the help